# Как прочитать символ или символы в середине строки из файла?

Tags: c++

Условие:

Имя входного файла input.txt
Имя выходного файла стандартный вывод

Дан файл input.txt, в котором содержится текст.
Напишите программу, которая найдет символ, который находится в середине файла.

Формат входных данных
Входной файл содержит не более 10^7 символов с ASCII-кодами от 33 до 126.

Формат выходных данных
Требуется вывести серединный символ входного файла на экран.
Если в файле чётное количество символов, программа должна вывести два символа, которые находятся в середине через пробел.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string buf;
    short k=0, n = 0;
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("middle.txt", ios::in);
    if(infile.is_open()){
        infile >> buf;
        n = buf.size();
        cout << n << endl;
         k = n/2;
        if(n%2 == 1) {
            cout << buf[k];
        }
        else cout << buf[k-1] << " " << buf[k];
    }
    else{
        cout << "File error."<< endl;
        return 1;
    }
    infile.close();

return 0;
}
```

Задачу решил, но вот как сюда воткнуть seekg/tellg, так и не понял. Если кто-нибудь знает, подскажите. Спасибо.

Comment: `seekg/tellg` и `ios::binary` при открытии к вашим услугам :) А, символы начинаются от 33 - тогда даже `ios::binary` не обязателен...

Comment: char *start = input.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg), *endt = input.seekg(0,std::ios_base::end);  и циклом посчитать между ними количество?

Comment: Стать на конец файла, получить `tellg`, найти средину...